# jquery-ui-draggable alignment guidelines

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Is it possible to show the alignment guidelines with a jquery-ui-draggable while dragging it relative to other jquery-ui-draggable?

This is not jquery-ui but you can take idea from this one https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exist that I'm aware of.  You'd have to implement a custom solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it should be a comment rather than answer i suppose.

Comment: I debated on rather this should be an answer or comment.  I decided on comment because your question asked if it was possible to do with jQuery-UI-draggable, and unfortunately the answer is no.  That said, if you find a way to do it, I'd love to know, as I was wanting this for a project almost a year ago, but didn't have time to implement a custom solution for it.

Comment: Well said, me too was not sure its not possible without canvas not in dom.